# Send a message with label

Tags: gmail-api

I would like to send an email with the Gmail API and apply a label to it, like this:

```
curl 'https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages/send'
-X POST \
-H 'Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_BEARER_TOKEN]'
-H 'Accept: application/json'
-H 'Content-Type: application/json'
--data-binary '{"raw":"RAW_DATA","labelIds":["my_label"]}'
```

but the label does not apply.
I have the following answer :

```
{
  "id": "MESSAGE_ID",
  "threadId": "THREAD_ID",
  "labelIds": ["SENT"]
}
```

I do not understand why ?

Comment: Have you tried defining the label separately and adding it in by the new labels name?

Comment: Normally the gmail API, should apply the `my_label` in addition to the `SENT` label to the message. When the message is sent I manage to add the label with the endpoint `/modify`, but I would like to do it in a single call.

Comment: My recommendation would be to start with everything in expanded notation before using the overloaded methods

Comment: @WilliamBoulay any resolution to this - having the same issue wondering if the api just wont allow you to set a label when using raw email?

Comment: @Boog I used two call api to solve my problem. One to send the email and also after one to modify the email and apply the label.